# Error dotConnect for Oracle to test a ASP.NET 2.2 app in Azure

Tags: .net-core, devart, azure-app-service-envrmnt, dotconnect

I am trialing dotConnect for Oracle to test a ASP.NET 2.2 app in Azure, to see if the web technology and database providers would work for us on a new project.

However, I recive:
[Error] Feature is not supported. This error is thrown by Devart .NET Standard assemblies if license key validation fails. Possible reasons: 1. License key is not found, refer to the "Licensing .NET Standard (.NET Core) Projects" article in the product documentation. 2. Your product edition (the key was generated for) doesn't support the feature you are trying to use, refer to the editions matrix. 3. Your key is outdated for using the current product version, renew the license key in the Customer Portal.

Any idea?

Comment: What folder have you use to include the DevArt's products in your azure deployment?

Answer (score 0):

You should install [dotConnect for Oracle Professional Trial](https://www.devart.com/dotconnect/oracle/docs/?LicensingStandard.html) to start your 30 days evaluation period. For more information, refer to https://www.devart.com/dotconnect/oracle/docs/?LicensingStandard.html.

Comment: As I mentioned, I have the trial installed and it works correctly locally.

The problem is that when I deploy it in an Azure App Service it can't find the .key file

Comment: You should add "License Key=trial:Devart.Data.Oracle.key;" to your connection string when Devart.Data.Oracle.key is located in the same folder with application in the deployment.

Or you can specify the absolute path: "License Key=trial:D:\AbsolutePath\Devart.Data.Oracle.key;".

Comment: I have the same issue using .NET Core 3.1. I appended "License Key=trial:Devart.Data.Oracle.key;" and copied my Devart.Data.Oracle.key from my local machine to the QA server (to the same folder as the app) but still get the same error. What is the next step to fix this?

Comment: Try specifying an absolute path, e.g.: "License Key=trial:C:\MyFolder\Devart.Data.Oracle.key;". If the issue persists, contact us via https://www.devart.com/company/contactform.html .